# VS2012 mixing C and Cpp, library clash

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, tr1

I am trying to combine some C and C++ code in a project, and before I had no issues with this, but I'm now trying out VS2012 for the first time and I get a lot of errors from a TR1 header that I didn't include explicitely.

I'm thinking it might be a mixup because it's trying to compile my c code with this cpp header. It looks like a C compiler error trying to understand C++ template code. Where can I figure this out from the VS2012 interface? Do I need to do something to my c and cpp files to make the compiler treat them properly?

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '<'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xtr1common   15  1   example~
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : '<' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xtr1common   15  1   example~
Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '<'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xtr1common   20  1   example~
Error   4   error C2059: syntax error : '<' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xtr1common   20  1   example~
Error   5   error C2016: C requires that a struct or union has at least one member  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xtr1common   28  1   example~
```

Comment: Show the code. From these particular error messages it's not easy to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: My ESP is weak today. So you may have show some code.

Comment: Here is the example project with include headers. Open the example in maxcpp-master/examples/msp/example~.sln    https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8165817/maxcpptest.zip

Comment: 14Mb? what ever happened to the minimum amount of code that can reproduce the error?

Comment: My code depends on an SDK and I don't know if I can reproduce it when I try to cut it loose. It would certainly take a lot more effort than it would take most people to download 14Mb of data.

Comment: Is no one in the mood to download 14mb and have a look? :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. It has been a while since I've used VS and forgot that it doesn't necessarily treat cpp files as c++. I had to set the "compile as" option to c++.